# how to update a table using a temporary variable

Tags: variables, plsql, sql-update, bind

I want to update a table inside a loop and I want to add the values stored in a temporary variable. part of code is shown here:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN temp_atr_val = temp_val THEN net_sales_home ELSE 0 END) into temp_variable
       FROM schemafinal_1;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE SAR ADD ('||temp_name||' number)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' UPDATE SAR b 
SET b.'||temp_name||' = temp_variable';
END LOOP;
END LOOP;   
END;
```

when i run the code as above it says ORA-00904: "TEMP_VARIABLE": invalid identifier
and when i put & before temp_variable it asks me for binding value and that value is populated in each cell.
if i use :temp_variable it says "ORA-01008: not all variables bound

I am new to pl/sql and oracle sql developer. please help

Answer (score 0):

You should either use 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' UPDATE SAR b  SET b.'||temp_name||' = ' || to_char(temp_variable);
or
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' UPDATE SAR b  SET b.'||temp_name||' = :a' using temp_variable

temp_variable is out of the scope so you fail with the update.

Comment: using your suggestion i was able to get rid of compilation error but its not showing any value but zero in each column but it should show numeric values.

Comment: Pardon, I misunderstand your question. If you have NULLs it means temp_variable is null. Tell me the value of temp_name.

Comment: i have a table name as look_up_table which has 3columns 

ATTRIBUTE_NPUT VALUE_FOR _ATR NAME_OF_COL
A CAT p_A_CAT
A RAT p_A_RAT
A PETER p_A_PETER
B LION p_B_LION
B DOG p_B_DOG

There is another table which is like this:


id net_sale_home A B
0 2 cat lion
1 3 cat lion
2 4 rat dog
4 2 peter lion
5 6 rat lion
now i am writing query to select sales corresponding to that value which is stored in the temp_val for that particular column whose value is stored in tem_atr_val:
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN temp_atr_val = temp_val THEN net_sales_home ELSE 0 END) into temp_variable
           FROM schemafinal_1;

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand the issue you've faced with. 1. which construction do you use: with to_char or with using? 2. what do you mean by 'it should show numeric values'? Only 1 stuff could be - temp_variable is null.

Comment: i have selected sum of sales from a table for those values in other column which are stored in a temporary variable. i put this sales value in another temporary variable named temp_variable. now i want to update a new table with these sales values which are stored in temp_variable

Comment: show me how your plsql looks now and the value of temp_variable

Comment: i want to do something like this with temporary variables:
sum(case when category = 'Accessible' then sales else 0 end) as Accessible,

and i wrote it as :
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN  temp_atr_val = '||temp_val||' THEN net_sales_home ELSE 0 END) into temp_variable
           FROM schemafinal_1;
will it fetch me the result? or temp_variable doesn't take any value?

Comment: print your sql on the script by dbms_output (because it is possible temp_val has null), execute your query and have a look does it whether return the value.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go-

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN temp_atr_val = temp_val THEN net_sales_home ELSE 0 END) into temp_variable
       FROM schemafinal_1;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE SAR ADD ('||temp_name||' number)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE SAR b SET b.'||temp_name||' = '|| temp_variable;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;   
END;
```